# Set a variable in a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this function to display a mysql table on my page and if table has new rows to update it.

I want to use a few buttons to change `'data.php?clas=Regularitate%20Sedan'` or `'data.php?clas='` to something else.

My final code to work like this:
-when I press button1 `$('#Table3').load('HERE TO BE VARIABLE1')` AND THE TABLE3 TO REFRESH
-when I press button2 `$('#Table3').load('HERE TO BE VARIABLE2')` AND THE TABLE3 TO REFRESH

```
<div id="show"></div>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function () {
        $('#Table3').load('data.php?clas=Regularitate%20Sedan')
        $('#Table2').load('data.php?clas=')
    }, 1500);
});
</script>
```

I tried this function

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var destinatie = "hello.html";
function choose(choice){
    destinatie = choice;
}
</script>
</head>
<button type="button" onclick="choose('/data.php?ral=1&clas=Regularitate%20Sedan&tur=1')">PS1</button>
```

I think it can change the `destinatie` variable, and on jquery I changed `$('#Table3').load('destinatie')`.

How do I call the jquery function?

Comment: You're not loading a _mysql table_, you are loading mysql data _into an HTML table_.  Additionally, why are you mixing inline `onclick` and jQuery? It'd be better to be consistent and use a jQuery event listener for your button... lastly, your question mentions two buttons, but you only have one button in the code above.  Please include an [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

put a data-choice attribute in your html and get it with :

```
$('button#IdOfYourChoice').attr('data-choice')
```

look at this ressource :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset